# How to turn off Nautilus autoplay under KDE?

Tags: linux, kde, nautilus, autoplay

Does anyone have an idea why when I insert a CD/DVD/flash nautilus opens as a default file manager under KDE instead of dolphin krusader? In my system settings krusader is set as the default manager, but still nautilus somehow keeps showing up, and I'm wondering how to change that?

I keep nautilus because it's a dropbox dependency... Ok, I know there are workarounds so one could use dropbox without nautilus but I didn't bother trying that out... I don't mind keeping nautilus but I just want it to be quiet :D

I have KDE 4.5.1 installed on an up-to-date Arch if that helps.

Comment: I use dropbox without nautilus. It's actually super easy to install that way.

Comment: Yeah me too (now), but at that time I wasn't.. =)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize how old this question was since it was at the top of the front page =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **[link](http://syafii.com/linux/161/how-to-disable-autorun-on-ubuntu/)** seems to be what you are looking for. The post is **ubuntu** specific thought...